# Visual Studio generates "Error: uninitialized local variable 'x' "and online Compiler does not - Why?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
int main() {
    int y, z, a, b, c;
    int x;
    double d;
    cout << "Enter Numbers! Enter -999 to Stop:\n";
    y = 0; z = 0; a = 0;
    b = 0; c = 0; d = 0;

while (x != -999) {

    cin >> x;

    if (x > 0) y++;
    if (x > 0) b += x;
    if (x == 0) z++;
    if (x < 0 && x != -999)a++;
    if (x < 0 && x != -999) c += x;



}
d = b * 1.0 / y * 1.0;
if (b == 0 || y == 0) {
    d = 0;
}

cout << "Total Positive Numbers are: " << y << endl;
cout << "Total Negative Numbers are: " << a << endl;
cout << "Total Zeros are: " << z << endl;
cout << "Sum of Positive Numbers is: " << b << endl;
cout << "Sum of Negative Numbers is: " << c << endl;
cout << "Average of Positive Numbers is: " << d * 1.0 << endl;
return 0;
```

}

The visual studio compiler says its "uninitialized local variable 'x' used" at line 13.

However, it has no problem on other online compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio is being kind to you here: the behaviour of reading an uninitialised variable is *undefined* in C++, and `(x != -999)` is an uninitialised read on the first encounter.

Don't ignore warnings issued by the other compilers.

Comment: then how can i fix this programme?? i am new to programming

Comment: @MemeReview: The quick fix is to set `x` to zero at the point of declaration. Later on in your programming life you'll settle upon more fancy ways.

Answer (score 1):

Reading an uninitialised variable (which you do) is not *required* to be a compiler error. It is defined by the standard as having "Undefined Behaviour". Which basically means that the compiler is allowed to compile your program, but can do *whatever it likes* to *any* part of your program, since it is now defined as having *no* well defined behaviour - so *anything* is OK.

In C++ it is ultimately the responsibility of the *programmer* to know *all* the rules of the language and *never* write anything that invokes UB *anywhere* and the compiler is *not* required to help you / diagnose your errors, it can just *assume* that you didn't write any UB and whatever result is OK if you did anyway.

There is *no safety net* / *no training wheels* in C++.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub